# Background Worker with disposable argument

Tags: c#, .net

I have a background worker that receive a disposable object as parameter.  The `RunWorkerAsync` method is called inside a using block.

Here is a simplified code sample

```
    private void SearchTest(string filter)
    {
        bgWorker.DoWork += bgWorker_DoWork;
        using (DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry())
        {
            using (var search = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry))
            {
                search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                search.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=group)(cn={0}))", filter);
                bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(search);
            }
        }
    }
    void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var searcher = (DirectorySearcher) e.Argument;
        var reportList = new List<String>();

        bgWorker.ReportProgress(0);

        SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll();
        foreach (SearchResult result in results)
        {
            reportList.Add(result.Properties["cn"][0]);

            bgWorker.ReportProgress(1);
        }
        e.Result= reportList;

    }
```

This code is working(ie: the argument isn't disposed at the end of the using block, the background worker is doing work while the end of the using block is hit), but I can't figure how the using block is working in that case.  Does the background worker argument is cloned and won't be disposed properly, will the `Dispose` method will be called upon background worker completion?  What's happen?

Edit: I removed the background worker and disposed the object after Daniel answer and it still work... so this is really a `DirectorySearcher` `Dispose`particularity... :

```
    private void SearchTest(string filter)
    {
        bgWorker.DoWork += bgWorker_DoWork;
        using (DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry())
        {
            using (var search = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry))
            {
                search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                search.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=group)(cn={0}))", filter);

                ////////////////////
                search.Dispose();
                ////////////////////

                var reportList = new List<String>();
                SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll();//Still work with the disposed instance
                foreach (SearchResult result in results)
                {
                    reportList.Add(result.Properties["cn"][0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That certainly looks like it should fail with an `ObjectDisposedException`...

Comment: You cannot use the *using* statement here, the object is going to be disposed before or while the thread is running.  Kaboom.  You'll need to dispose it in your DoWork event handler or in a RunWorkerCompleted event handler.

Comment: @HansPassant: I don't think that there is a *kaboom* in this specific case, see my answer.

Comment: @Hans Passant I know this seem weird but, this code is working.

Comment: @Guish It's working by luck. A future version of .Net might start throwing an `ObjectDisposedException`, so definitely move the `using` to the worker.

Comment: It is the ultimate threading race bug.  This tends to fail when the machine is heavily loaded or you extend your program and start using threadpool threads.

Comment: @Matthew Watson You are right, I will certainly change this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object is certainly being disposed at the end of the using block so your background worker is using a disposed instance.

My guess as to why it still works is that `DirectorySearcher` only has a `Dispose` method because it derives from `Component` and doesn't actually make use of it, i.e. `Dispose` doesn't do anything and the methods of this class don't care about whether Dispose has been called or not.

Comment: I looked at the code for `FindAll()` and it doesn't check if the object is disposed, so that might explain why it doesn't throw the exception. Looks very unsafe to do/might break in a future release.

Comment: @ Matthew Watson:  I was thinking of doing the dispose at background worker completion instead.

Comment: It has a use for Dispose(), there's a Marshal.ReleaseComObject() call underneath.

Comment: @Daniel Higarth The Dispose method actually call the base component `Dispose` method

Comment: Yeah, I now had a look at the code too: It does some things but apparently none that affect the functionality of the methods used by the OP.